# targetNamespace in XML schema causes groups to be invisible

Tags: xml, xsd

When I specify targetNamespace in XML Schema, I receive errors (MS Visual Studio Editor and XSD Tool) "undeclared model group 'group name'". I've even tried group example from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_indicators.asp) but all the same. 
When I remove targetNamespace attribute - everything ok.
Any ideas?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="unqualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="ns">

<xs:group name="persongroup">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="birthday" type="xs:date"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:element name="person" type="personinfo"/>

<xs:complexType name="personinfo">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:group ref="persongroup"/>
    <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: ok, found the answer [here](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/35/179690.aspx) - references to groups / types must be namespace qualified if targetNamespace is used.

Comment: It's OK to answer your own question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The references to groups / types must be namespace qualified if targetNamespace is used.  [reference](http://www.dotnet247.com/247reference/msgs/35/179690.aspx)

Comment: Link is dead. Goes to dotnet247 home page.